# how to remove attributes from dynamic generated elements

Tags: javascript, jquery

first this is the picture , the calender is generated using a cms and every element has an onclick event

[image]

The **back** and **forward** buttons when clicked will make a new ajax request and returns a new set of elements with their ***onclick*** event

i want to attach my own event handler on all the elements so i use the **jquery** ***delegate*** method on the table and select all the **anchors**

the problem is the 2 events fires at the same time so i want to negative the onclick event and fire only my version by removing the ***onclick***  **attribute**

---

the element being generated by the cms :

```
<a class="elem" href="..." onclick="function()">text</a>
```

my version of the delegate method to select all the elements

```
$("table").delegate(".elem","click", function() {
        //DO SOMETHING    
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Try putting this before your .delegate( ) call: (untested)

```
$('table .elem').each( function(i, elem) {
    elem.onclick = false;
});
```

It basically removes the existing onclick for each of those elements, allowing you to replace it with your own function.

Comment: the problem when i press next or previews month a new set of tags will be loaded via an ajax call and inserted and also they will have an onclick event

Comment: You can set up a function in your ajax success area, and run this snippet in that function and it will clear out all of those new element's onclick events as well.  You may have to edit the function to only select the new elements though, so you don't kill any previous onclick events that you may have added yourself.

Comment: so the ajax success event run before or after the element is inserted to the dom ? (the element is inserted = successful ajax call then insert elements to the dom ) the success event runs when ? after the success or after the insertion ?

Comment: You would run the ajax, and then inside the ajax success event, you would attach the HTML to the dom, and then run that snippet.

Comment: the problem i dont have any control on the script that generate the table its auto generated in another place

Comment: Do you have control over when the data gets pulled in?  If not there's not much you can do except run the script to remove the current onclicks and replace with your own every second or so and hope someone doesn't click the link between when the data comes in and when the script runs.

Answer (score 0):

In jQuery 1.7 they introduced an `off` method that will

> Remove an event handler

http://api.jquery.com/.off/

Comment: the problem when i press next or previews month a new set of tags will be loaded via an ajax call and inserted and also they will have an onclick event